# Show results from both word based suggestions and own completion provider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio Code extension, that, using the Language Server Protocol, provides a completion list. My problem is that after implementing it, users have lost the completion based on the document contents.

I want completion to show *both* my own provider's results as well as VSCode's word based suggestions.

Non-Working example:

[image]

Working example:

[image]

(https://github.com/APerricone/harbourCodeExtension/issues/16)

I tried to set `isIncomplete` to `false`, without any improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a VSCode feature called "word-based suggestions" (see the `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions"` setting). Word based suggestions are by default provided whenever all other registered completion providers fail to return any results.

I'm not aware of any way to have word-based suggestions be *merged* with your own provider's results instead. [This statement by a VSCode dev](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15411#issuecomment-270070750) seems to confirm that this isn't possible:

> > *Why not include string based matching even when there is a completion provider returning suggestions?*
>
> Each provider gets a [rank](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/a6435b1cbd1417b0d334ea9018f5371df198898f/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L4072) depending on the selector it uses when registering. The word based provider usually has the lowest score and the [rule](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/a6435b1cbd1417b0d334ea9018f5371df198898f/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L4085) is that lower ranked providers aren't asked if higher ranked providers produced a result. That is to avoid duplicates and spam.

The doc comment of `registerCompletionItemProvider()` is still the same, so I don't think anything has changed in this regard since then. Perhaps you could open a feature request for this, but I'm not sure how high the chances of it being implemented are.

However, there is a simple workaround: just implement word-based suggestions yourself. If you use [`CompletionItemKind.Text`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemKind.Text), it should look the same as VSCode's built-in provider. I assume that to provide completion, you already have to scan the document contents anyway. As an added bonus, this allows avoiding duplicates like mentioned in the issue.

---

Possibly related issue: [#21611](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21611)