# VSCode is not showing custom completion suggestion if cursor is positioned on specific character

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I'm making a vscode extension to provide syntax highlighting and suggestions for a custom language that extends the HTML lang. I'm using the CompletionItemProvider API.

In this language we got commands wrapped in $%-$ like *$%FOR (...)$* or *$%IF (...)$*, so I want to show a suggestion of the available commands when I type $%.

But for some reason, it doesn't work when the cursor is on the % character.

Here is a simplified version of the code. I basically based on the completion sample (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/completions-sample/src/extension.ts):

```js
    const completionProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
        '*',
        {
            provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) {

                let linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);

                if (!linePrefix.endsWith("$%")) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                console.log("should show suggestions");

                return [
                    new vscode.CompletionItem('IF', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method),
                    new vscode.CompletionItem('FOR', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method)
                ];
            }
        }
    );

context.subscriptions.push(completionProvider);
```

The function takes the text typed on the editor and checks if the user has just typed $%, if so then shows the list of suggestions

The result is a pop up whit a "No suggestions" message:
[image: Imgur]

But if I check for another trigger string that ends with another char different from '%', changing the line

```js
if (!linePrefix.endsWith("$%")) {
```

to this

```js
if (!linePrefix.endsWith("$%$")) {
```

or this

```js
if (!linePrefix.endsWith("$%.")) {
```

it works!

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the cursor being "on" the `%`? Because it seems to work fine here: https://i.imgur.com/4akIcH8.png

Comment: I've edited my question with the images of the behaviors I'm getting. As I said, I get a No suggestions pop up when I'm on '$%' but it works otherwise.
Can you share me the code that works for you ?

Comment: Err, well.. I just copy-pasted yours. :D

Comment: Ok, I found something, It seems that it actually work in some languages but it doesn't work on HTML language. Even if I explicitly set the DocumentSelector to "html".
But I need it to work on HTML :/

Comment: Oh, hm.. I think completion providers are ranked based on how specific their document selectors are? Maybe the native HTML completion provider ranks more highly than your `*` wildcard selector, and thus your results aren't shown. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219340/2631715

Comment: "the rule is that lower ranked providers aren't asked if higher ranked providers produced a result. That is to avoid duplicates and spam."

Comment: seems legit. But why changing my trigger string to, for example "$%$" it works ?
Plus that, the console.log is being outputted, so it means the provider has run indeed and the validation was successful. It is really giving me headaches

Comment: Hm, good point, if it was the ranking, that shouldn't make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I reset the setting of VS code, now it's working.
Warning: All the installed extensions will be removed.