# emmet vscode does not prompt the names of html classes that are already in the html file

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, emmet

I used VS Code and remember emmet prompted me with class names to complete. Now it doesn't work. I've tried all the plugins, all the settings, but nothing helps.

I want vscode to show the names of the classes that are already in
this html file. **no from html to css or from css to html. i need html to html**

When I enter a point it gives me:

[image]

I want emmet in VS Code give it:

[image]

plugin IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML and html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport and other plugins.

Comment: what icon theme are you using? those might just be regular text suggestions. I wonder if this is a case of https://stackoverflow.com/q/55219025/11107541

Comment: "_html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport doesn't work_" did you install [the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion) that contributes that setting? What did you set the setting to?

Comment: can you provide a code block [mre]? I don't see any classes in the screenshot you showed of what you have that start with "cont". And just out of curiosity, how is it that you both have a screenshot of it working and not working at the same time, and why do the screenshots have different themes and UI styles?

Comment: please [edit] your question to provide a [mre], and write up the answer you found (see [answer]).

Comment: I just want vscode to tell me the names of the classes that are already in this html file. otherwise I have to drive these classes all over again

Comment: plugin IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML can't do what i want. Maybe there's another way get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem is the plugin [SCSS Everywhere](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion)!it does exactly what I wanted. but it has one small problem to show the new classes you need to when you write the name of the class to remove one character so it displays a new class that would be added earlier