# Global identifiers for own intelliSense for vscode LSP extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm trying to create own intelliSense, but don't know how to leave default helper from the open file conext (Global identifiers)
[image]

If I implement `connection.onCompletion` method the Global identifiers will disappear.
[image]

I may be wrong about the name "Global identifiers" of the instrument. Just couldn’t find another mention

Has anyone encountered that?
Or maybe someone knows how to get the global identifiers for LSP?

Comment: the global identifiers are supplied by another `CompletionItemProvider`, VSC sorts them by relevance in the list, possibly the same reason that you don't get globals when you type a possible Emmet command, if VSC does not call that global-provider you don't see its results

Comment: do you supply the same completions no matter what is before the cursor, that will show the list on every char typed

Comment: did you supply word separators in the language json file

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for the comment.
I just started implementing the complition and so far I have only added fixed return values, because I want to understand how not to override the default implementation with the global identifiers.

I supply only triggerCharacters in ServerCapabilities

`completionProvider:{
 resolveProvider:true,
 triggerCharacters:['.']
},`

Comment: From there [vscode-extension-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/lsp-sample/server/src/server.ts)

Comment: if JavaScript supplies the global identifiers is that because it has made an AST and analyzed the source cod and thus is able to extract the global identifiers. You have to parse the language you serve.

Comment: @rioV8 I have an ANTLR parser for analyzed the source code, but I mean the other thing. As I understand it, vscode has a default helper from the open file continects and when I override the method `connection.onCompletion` it is disabled

Comment: I may be wrong about the name "Global identifiers" of the instrument.
Just couldn’t find another mention

Comment: do you want to add completions to `.js` files or to your own language files

Comment: @rioV8 My own language

Comment: then why do you expect VSC to extract the global variables for you, VSC has no knowledge of the syntax of all the languages, that is the task of the Language Server

Comment: @rioV8 I edited the description of the question. Maybe it will help to get what I mean

Comment: that is the `word` in open files completion provider a standard VSC provider, maybe ask by issue why that provider is not called when your provider supplies items

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks you,
I found answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219025/show-results-from-both-word-based-suggestions-and-own-completion-provider